# Cant read properly XML from Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to read a XML file with Javascript , it is for a assignment in school so i cant use jQuery it has to be Javascript. Basicly i can read ONE value but not the other

This is my JS that is resposible for reading the XML value. It will read startLng but it gives me startLat is undefined. But if i check the XML file the startLat is not undefined. I cant see what the problem is here.

What i am trying to do is to get the LatitudeDegrees and LongitudeDegrees from the XML file. But it only gives me the LongitudeDegrees and says the LatitudeDegrees is undefined. What am i doing wrong here?

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      getLatLang(xmlhttp);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "G1.TCX", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

    function getLatLang(xml)
{
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Trackpoint");
      startLat = x[0].getElementsByTagName("Position")[0].getElementsByTagName("LatitudeDegrees")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      startLng = x[0].getElementsByTagName("Position")[0].getElementsByTagName("LongitudeDegrees")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  

}
```

This is the XML file

```
      <Trackpoint>
    <Time>2008-10-28T15:58:22Z</Time>
    <Position>
      <LatitudeDegrees>59.4111992</LatitudeDegrees>
      <LongitudeDegrees>13.5304104</LongitudeDegrees>
    </Position>
    <AltitudeMeters>85.6945801</AltitudeMeters>
    <DistanceMeters>0.2149343</DistanceMeters>
    <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
      <Value>116</Value>
    </HeartRateBpm>
    <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
    <Extensions>
      <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" CadenceSensor="Footpod"/>
    </Extensions>
  </Trackpoint>
```

Comment: Consider to insert minimal but complete code snippets to allow us to reproduce the problem. The XML snippet you have posted is not complete as the `xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t"` attribute uses the prefix `xsi` but does not declare it. When I correct the XML and try to make a minimal snippet at https://jsfiddle.net/jnq0qg3u/1/ then I get the wanted output with Firefox, Chrome and Edge, there is no failure to access the latitude.

Comment: The thing is the XML file is over 1000 rows , so posting it here would be alot of useless text also forgot to say that the XML is loaded from a file

Comment: Well, try to reduce things to allow us to reproduce the problem, either you find the cause of the problem that way of your own or we can then identify it. As for loading from a file, if the XML is well-formed then it doesn't matter whether you parse a string or from a file, you say you can parse the file but your code doesn't find an element, so present a minimal but complete sample that demonstrates that problem.

Comment: I solved it , the problem was i did not have a window onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved.

The problem was i did not have a document load.